# How can I forward an e-mail (the original) that I am half way through writing a draft reply to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In outlook, the original message appears in my inbox with [Draft] next to it, and clicking on it I can continue editing my reply.

I want to e-mail the original to a colleague, but the forward button is greyed out.

How can I do this without discarding my draft and forwarding it? Is there a way to make outlook separate a draft from an item in my inbox? It should really be in the drafts folder like most e-mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, double-clicking the e-mail in the inbox opens the original in a new window, which you can then forward.

I expected it to just pop-out the e-mail in the right pane (the draft) but it unintuitively opens the original.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your own answer, you can click pop-out so your reply is now a separate window, giving you full access to the original email(s)/Outlook